# Multiselect Dropdown z-index not working inside a scroll container div

Tags: jquery, html, dom

Multiselect Dropdown z-index not working inside a scroll container div. It shows scroll instead of opening it like another drop-down.

Sample code : "http://jsfiddle.net/rousseauo/acg2Lco8/"

```js
// Helped by the code of : pete-experimenter
// Due to bootstrap-multiselect.js not being available on CDN, it's included first below.
// My code begins on line 570


/**
 * bootstrap-multiselect.js 1.0.0
 * https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect
 *
 * Copyright 2012, 2013 David Stutz
 * 
 * Dual licensed under the BSD-3-Clause and the Apache License, Version 2.0.
 * See the README.
 */! function ($) {
    "use strict"; // jshint ;_;

    if (typeof ko != 'undefined' && ko.bindingHandlers && !ko.bindingHandlers.multiselect) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.multiselect = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {},
            update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                var ms = $(element).data('multiselect');
                if (!ms) {
                    $(element).multiselect(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()));
                } else if (allBindingsAccessor().options && allBindingsAccessor().options().length !== ms.originalOptions.length) {
                    ms.updateOriginalOptions();
                    $(element).multiselect('rebuild');
                }
            }
        };
    }

    function Multiselect(select, options) {

        this.options = this.getOptions(options);
        this.$select = $(select);
        this.originalOptions = this.$select.clone()[0].options;
        //we have to clone to create a new reference
        this.query = '';
        this.searchTimeout = null;

        this.options.multiple = this.$select.attr('multiple') == "multiple";

        this.$container = $(this.options.buttonContainer).append('<button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle ' + this.options.buttonClass + '" data-toggle="dropdown">' + this.options.buttonText(this.getSelected(), this.$select) + '</button>')
            .append('<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu' + (this.options.dropRight ? ' pull-right' : '') + '"></ul>');

        // Manually add button width if set.
        if (this.options.buttonWidth) {
            $('button', this.$container).css({
                'width': this.options.buttonWidth
            });
        }

        // Keep the tab index from the select.
        var tabindex = this.$select.attr('tabindex');
        if (tabindex) {
            $('button', this.$container).attr('tabindex', tabindex);
        }

        // Set max height of dropdown menu to activate auto scrollbar.
        if (this.options.maxHeight) {
            // TODO: Add a class for this option to move the css declarations.
            $('.multiselect-container', this.$container).css({
                'max-height': this.options.maxHeight + 'px',
                    'overflow-y': 'auto',
                    'overflow-x': 'hidden'
            });
        }

        // Enable filtering.
        if (this.options.enableFiltering || this.options.enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering) {
            var enableFilterLength = Math.max(this.options.enableFiltering, this.options.enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering);
            if (this.$select.find('option').length >= enableFilterLength) {
                this.buildFilter();
            }
        }

        // Build select all if enabled.
        this.buildSelectAll();
        this.buildDropdown();
        this.updateButtonText();

        this.$select.hide().after(this.$container);
    };

    Multiselect.prototype = {

        defaults: {
            // Default text function will either print 'None selected' in case no
            // option is selected, or a list of the selected options up to a length of 3 selected options.
            // If more than 3 options are selected, the number of selected options is printed.
            buttonText: function (options, select) {
                if (options.length == 0) {
                    return this.nonSelectedText + '<b class="caret"></b>';
                } else if (options.length > 3) {
                    return options.length + ' ' + this.nSelectedText + ' <b class="caret"></b>';
                } else {
                    var selected = '';
                    options.each(function () {
                        var label = ($(this).attr('label') !== undefined) ? $(this).attr('label') : $(this).html();

                        selected += label + ', ';
                    });
                    return selected.substr(0, selected.length - 2) + ' <b class="caret"></b>';
                }
            },
            // Like the buttonText option to update the title of the button.
            buttonTitle: function (options, select) {
                var selected = '';
                options.each(function () {
                    selected += $(this).text() + ', ';
                });
                return selected.substr(0, selected.length - 2);
            },
            // Is triggered on change of the selected options.
            onChange: function (option, checked) {

            },
            buttonClass: 'btn',
            dropRight: false,
            selectedClass: 'active',
            buttonWidth: 'auto',
            buttonContainer: '<div class="btn-group" />',
            // Maximum height of the dropdown menu.
            // If maximum height is exceeded a scrollbar will be displayed.
            maxHeight: false,
            includeSelectAllOption: false,
            selectAllText: ' Select all',
            selectAllValue: 'multiselect-all',
            enableFiltering: false,
            enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: false,
            filterPlaceholder: 'Search',
            // possible options: 'text', 'value', 'both'
            filterBehavior: 'text',
            preventInputChangeEvent: false,
            nonSelectedText: 'None selected',
            nSelectedText: 'selected'
        },

        constructor: Multiselect,

        // Will build an dropdown element for the given option.
        createOptionValue: function (element) {
            if ($(element).is(':selected')) {
                $(element).attr('selected', 'selected').prop('selected', true);
            }

            // Support the label attribute on options.
            var label = $(element).attr('label') || $(element).html();
            var value = $(element).val();
            var inputType = this.options.multiple ? "checkbox" : "radio";

            var $li = $('<li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><label class="' + inputType + '"><input type="' + inputType + '" /></label></a></li>');

            var selected = $(element).prop('selected') || false;
            var $checkbox = $('input', $li);
            $checkbox.val(value);

            if (value == this.options.selectAllValue) {
                $checkbox.parent().parent().addClass('multiselect-all');
            }

            $('label', $li).append(" " + label);

            $('.multiselect-container', this.$container).append($li);

            if ($(element).is(':disabled')) {
                $checkbox.attr('disabled', 'disabled').prop('disabled', true).parents('li').addClass('disabled');
            }

            $checkbox.prop('checked', selected);

            if (selected && this.options.selectedClass) {
                $checkbox.parents('li').addClass(this.options.selectedClass);
            }
        },

        toggleActiveState: function (shouldBeActive) {
            if (this.$select.attr('disabled') == undefined) {
                $('button.multiselect.dropdown-toggle', this.$container).removeClass('disabled');
            } else {
                $('button.multiselect.dropdown-toggle', this.$container).addClass('disabled');
            }
        },

        // Add the select all option to the select.
        buildSelectAll: function () {
            var alreadyHasSelectAll = this.$select[0][0] ? this.$select[0][0].value == this.options.selectAllValue : false;

            // If options.includeSelectAllOption === true, add the include all checkbox.
            if (this.options.includeSelectAllOption && this.options.multiple && !alreadyHasSelectAll) {
                this.$select.prepend('<option value="' + this.options.selectAllValue + '">' + this.options.selectAllText + '</option>');
            }
        },

        // Build the dropdown and bind event handling.
        buildDropdown: function () {
            this.toggleActiveState();

            this.$select.children().each($.proxy(function (index, element) {
                // Support optgroups and options without a group simultaneously.
                var tag = $(element).prop('tagName').toLowerCase();
                if (tag == 'optgroup') {
                    var group = element;
                    var groupName = $(group).prop('label');

                    // Add a header for the group.
                    var $li = $('<li><label class="multiselect-group"></label></li>');
                    $('label', $li).text(groupName);
                    $('.multiselect-container', this.$container).append($li);

                    // Add the options of the group.
                    $('option', group).each($.proxy(function (index, element) {
                        this.createOptionValue(element);
                    }, this));
                } else if (tag == 'option') {
                    this.createOptionValue(element);
                } else {
                    // Ignore illegal tags.
                }
            }, this));

            // Bind the change event on the dropdown elements.
            $('.multiselect-container li input', this.$container).on('change', $.proxy(function (event) {
                var checked = $(event.target).prop('checked') || false;
                var isSelectAllOption = $(event.target).val() == this.options.selectAllValue;

                // Apply or unapply the configured selected class.
                if (this.options.selectedClass) {
                    if (checked) {
                        $(event.target).parents('li').addClass(this.options.selectedClass);
                    } else {
                        $(event.target).parents('li').removeClass(this.options.selectedClass);
                    }
                }

                var $option = $('option', this.$select).filter(function () {
                    return $(this).val() == $(event.target).val();
                });

                var $optionsNotThis = $('option', this.$select).not($option);
                var $checkboxesNotThis = $('input', this.$container).not($(event.target));

                // Toggle all options if the select all option was changed.
                if (isSelectAllOption) {
                    $checkboxesNotThis.filter(function () {
                        return $(this).is(':checked') != checked;
                    }).trigger('click');
                }

                if (checked) {
                    $option.prop('selected', true);

                    if (this.options.multiple) {
                        $option.attr('selected', 'selected');
                    } else {
                        if (this.options.selectedClass) {
                            $($checkboxesNotThis).parents('li').removeClass(this.options.selectedClass);
                        }

                        $($checkboxesNotThis).prop('checked', false);

                        $optionsNotThis.removeAttr('selected').prop('selected', false);

                        // It's a single selection, so close.
                        $(this.$container).find(".multiselect.dropdown-toggle").click();
                    }

                    if (this.options.selectedClass == "active") {
                        $optionsNotThis.parents("a").css("outline", "");
                    }

                } else {
                    $option.removeAttr('selected').prop('selected', false);
                }

                this.updateButtonText();

                this.options.onChange($option, checked);

                this.$select.change();

                if (this.options.preventInputChangeEvent) {
                    return false;
                }
            }, this));

            $('.multiselect-container li a', this.$container).on('touchstart click', function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                $(event.target).blur();
            });

            // Keyboard support.
            this.$container.on('keydown', $.proxy(function (event) {
                if ($('input[type="text"]', this.$container).is(':focus')) return;
                if ((event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27) && this.$container.hasClass('open')) {
                    // Close on tab or escape.
                    $(this.$container).find(".multiselect.dropdown-toggle").click();
                } else {
                    var $items = $(this.$container).find("li:not(.divider):visible a");

                    if (!$items.length) {
                        return;
                    }

                    var index = $items.index($items.filter(':focus'));

                    // Navigation up.
                    if (event.keyCode == 38 && index > 0) {
                        index--;
                    }
                    // Navigate down.
                    else if (event.keyCode == 40 && index < $items.length - 1) {
                        index++;
                    } else if (!~index) {
                        index = 0;
                    }

                    var $current = $items.eq(index);
                    $current.focus();

                    // Override style for items in li:active.
                    if (this.options.selectedClass == "active") {
                        $current.css("outline", "thin dotted #333").css("outline", "5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color");

                        $items.not($current).css("outline", "");
                    }

                    if (event.keyCode == 32 || event.keyCode == 13) {
                        var $checkbox = $current.find('input');

                        $checkbox.prop("checked", !$checkbox.prop("checked"));
                        $checkbox.change();
                    }

                    event.stopPropagation();
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }, this));
        },

        // Build and bind filter.
        buildFilter: function () {
            $('.multiselect-container', this.$container).prepend('<div class="input-prepend"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-search"></i></span><input class="multiselect-search" type="text" placeholder="' + this.options.filterPlaceholder + '"></div>');

            $('.multiselect-search', this.$container).val(this.query).on('click', function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            }).on('keydown', $.proxy(function (event) {
                // This is useful to catch "keydown" events after the browser has
                // updated the control.
                clearTimeout(this.searchTimeout);

                this.searchTimeout = this.asyncFunction($.proxy(function () {

                    if (this.query != event.target.value) {
                        this.query = event.target.value;

                        $.each($('.multiselect-container li', this.$container), $.proxy(function (index, element) {
                            var value = $('input', element).val();
                            if (value != this.options.selectAllValue) {
                                var text = $('label', element).text();
                                var value = $('input', element).val();
                                if (value && text && value != this.options.selectAllValue) {
                                    // by default lets assume that element is not
                                    // interesting for this search
                                    var showElement = false;

                                    var filterCandidate = '';
                                    if ((this.options.filterBehavior == 'text' || this.options.filterBehavior == 'both')) {
                                        filterCandidate = text;
                                    }
                                    if ((this.options.filterBehavior == 'value' || this.options.filterBehavior == 'both')) {
                                        filterCandidate = value;
                                    }

                                    if (this.options.enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering && filterCandidate.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                                        showElement = true;
                                    } else if (filterCandidate.indexOf(this.query) > -1) {
                                        showElement = true;
                                    }

                                    if (showElement) {
                                        $(element).show();
                                    } else {
                                        $(element).hide();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }, this));
                    }
                }, this), 300, this);
            }, this));
        },

        // Destroy - unbind - the plugin.
        destroy: function () {
            this.$container.remove();
            this.$select.show();
        },

        // Refreshs the checked options based on the current state of the select.
        refresh: function () {
            $('option', this.$select).each($.proxy(function (index, element) {
                var $input = $('.multiselect-container li input', this.$container).filter(function () {
                    return $(this).val() == $(element).val();
                });

                if ($(element).is(':selected')) {
                    $input.prop('checked', true);

                    if (this.options.selectedClass) {
                        $input.parents('li').addClass(this.options.selectedClass);
                    }
                } else {
                    $input.prop('checked', false);

                    if (this.options.selectedClass) {
                        $input.parents('li').removeClass(this.options.selectedClass);
                    }
                }

                if ($(element).is(":disabled")) {
                    $input.attr('disabled', 'disabled').prop('disabled', true).parents('li').addClass('disabled');
                } else {
                    $input.removeAttr('disabled').prop('disabled', false).parents('li').removeClass('disabled');
                }
            }, this));

            this.updateButtonText();
        },

        // Select an option by its value.
        select: function (value) {
            var $option = $('option', this.$select).filter(function () {
                return $(this).val() == value;
            });
            var $checkbox = $('.multiselect-container li input', this.$container).filter(function () {
                return $(this).val() == value;
            });

            if (this.options.selectedClass) {
                $checkbox.parents('li').addClass(this.options.selectedClass);
            }

            $checkbox.prop('checked', true);

            $option.attr('selected', 'selected').prop('selected', true);

            this.updateButtonText();
            this.options.onChange($option, true);
        },

        // Deselect an option by its value.
        deselect: function (value) {
            var $option = $('option', this.$select).filter(function () {
                return $(this).val() == value;
            });
            var $checkbox = $('.multiselect-container li input', this.$container).filter(function () {
                return $(this).val() == value;
            });

            if (this.options.selectedClass) {
                $checkbox.parents('li').removeClass(this.options.selectedClass);
            }

            $checkbox.prop('checked', false);

            $option.removeAttr('selected').prop('selected', false);

            this.updateButtonText();
            this.options.onChange($option, false);
        },

        // Rebuild the whole dropdown menu.
        rebuild: function () {
            $('.multiselect-container', this.$container).html('');

            this.buildSelectAll();
            this.buildDropdown(this.$select, this.options);
            this.updateButtonText();

            // Enable filtering.
            if (this.options.enableFiltering || this.options.enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering) {
                this.buildFilter();
            }
        },

        // Get options by merging defaults and given options.
        getOptions: function (options) {
            return $.extend({}, this.defaults, options);
        },

        updateButtonText: function () {
            var options = this.getSelected();

            // First update the displayed button text.
            $('button', this.$container).html(this.options.buttonText(options, this.$select));

            // Now update the title attribute of the button.
            $('button', this.$container).attr('title', this.options.buttonTitle(options, this.$select));

        },

        // Get all selected options.
        getSelected: function () {
            return $('option:selected[value!="' + this.options.selectAllValue + '"]', this.$select);
        },

        updateOriginalOptions: function () {
            this.originalOptions = this.$select.clone()[0].options;
        },

        asyncFunction: function (callback, timeout, self) {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 3);
            return setTimeout(function () {
                callback.apply(self || window, args);
            }, timeout);
        }
    };

    $.fn.multiselect = function (option, parameter) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var data = $(this).data('multiselect'),
                options = typeof option == 'object' && option;

            // Initialize the multiselect.
            if (!data) {
                $(this).data('multiselect', (data = new Multiselect(this, options)));
            }

            // Call multiselect method.
            if (typeof option == 'string') {
                data[option](parameter);
            }
        });
    };

    $.fn.multiselect.Constructor = Multiselect;

    $(function () {
        $("select[data-role=multiselect]").multiselect();
    });

}(window.jQuery);



/**
 *  MY CODE --------------------------------------------------
 *  ----------------------------------------------------------
 */


$('#multiSelect').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    buttonWidth: '200px',
});
```

```css
#scrollMe {
    height:150px;
    background-color:yellow;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <!-- Content Table -->
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="scrollMe" class="col-md-12">
                <select id="multiSelect" class="form-control multiselect" multiple="multiple">
                    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <br>
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->
</div>
```

Dropdown is opening inside div and create a unnecessary scroll.

Comment: Where is `sample code` ?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay code is attached with question and also there is a link to jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need just only to set: `overflow: inherit !important;`

Your updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kLn28n63/

Comment: The issue is described as "not working inside a scroll container div", so I would say a div that scrolls is a requirement. Setting the overflow to inherit disallows the div from scrolling. I don't think this should be an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have applied css to the #scrollMe div. Just change it

```
#scrollMe {
    height: auto;
    background-color: yellow;
    /* overflow-y: auto; */
    /* overflow-x: hidden; */
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Notice I have commented

```
`/* overflow-y: auto; */`
    `/* overflow-x: hidden; */`
```

Comment: yes it is working but for that i need to make height auto. I want fixed height for div

Answer (score -1):

Remove margin from `.ms-options-wrap > .ms-options` class.

```
.ms-options-wrap > .ms-options{margin-bottom: 0;}
```