# Multiselect Dropdown issue when inside a scroll container div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd like the Multiselect Dropdown to float over its container (a scrolling div), just like a regular select does.

I've tried changing the div overflow options, but that causes other elements inside it to behave improperly (i.e., they show, instead of triggering the scroll).

The question has been perfectly exposed previously:

[Multiselect Dropdown z-index not working inside a scroll container div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45186902/multiselect-dropdown-z-index-not-working-inside-a-scroll-container-div)

...but the author was satisfied with an answer that seems to get rid of the overflow.

I made a slight modification in the code of the previous link, adding a second regular select below everything. It must be shown just when the div is scrolled down, while the multiselect should float over, ignoring the overflow setting.

Is that possible?

Here is the code (95% is just a copy from the post above):

http://jsfiddle.net/danielnh/1pwLncmr/2/

```
#scrollMe {
height:150px;
background-color:yellow;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x:hidden;
padding:20px;
}
```

..

```
        <div id="scrollMe" class="col-md-12">
            <select id="multiSelect" class="form-control multiselect" multiple="multiple">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>
            <select class="form-control">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
            <br><br><br><br>
             <select class="form-control">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option div needs to be fixed or absolute position, for it to ignore the overflow.

Take a look below and read the comment, i added two lines of code in `Multiselect` function.

```
        $('#multiSelect').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            buttonWidth: '200px', 
        }).parent().find(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(){ 
        // MyCode
        // handle the position of the fixed div
        var offSet = $(this).offset();
        $(this).parent().find(".multiselect-container").css({
             position:"fixed",
             top:offSet.top + $(this).outerHeight(),
             left: offSet.left
          });
        });
```

Comment: Good observation +1

Comment: @Alen, thank you so much for you reply. Unfortunatly, the change you propposed refers to the library code, so I belive I'm unable to actually implementing it. If you go down to the bottom of the code, you'll se a comment like "MY CODE"... followed by 5 lines. Everything above is just the library (that was not availabe and had to be explicitly included).

Is there a way to implement a similar behaviour without changing the library code?

Comment: Ok i updated the code, and made small change to "MY CODE". have a look

Comment: Alen, that was really a great solution!
I've made a slight change to avoid reffering to the library inner classes by substituing ".dropdown-toggle" with "button" and ".multiselect-container" with "ul".

But I've not been able to avoid the weird behaviour when scrolling down the div: the list stays fixed, instead of moving around with the main component... Any ideas?

Comment: Add window.onscroll and hide the ul when scrolling. or You could have an absolute position instead.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, Alen. I had to treat window scroll and the div scroll separatly, but in the end, it all worked out.

Bellow is the final code. It's a bit different from the original fiddle, since I use another component to generate the checkbox list in the real system, but I belive it's comprehendable.

Comment: //reposition checkbox list ignoring the limits of scrollable div
    $("select.multipleSelect").multipleSelect().parent().find("button").click(  function () {
      var offSet = $(this).offset();
      $(this).next().css({
        position:"fixed",
        top:offSet.top + $(this).outerHeight()-window.pageYOffset,
        left: offSet.left
      });
    });

Comment: //hide checkbox list when there is a scroll inside the DIV
    $("select.multipleSelect").parents().scroll(function(){
      $(this).find("select.multipleSelect").map(function () {
        if ($(this).next().find("button").next().css("display")!='none') {
          $(this).next().find("button").click();
        }
      });
    });

Comment: //hide checkbox list when there is a scroll inside the window
  window.onscroll = function () {
    $("select.multipleSelect").map(function () {
          if ($(this).next().find("button").next().css("display")!='none') {
            $(this).next().find("button").click();
          }
        }
    );
  }